# AlarmManager alternatives for persistent frequent scheduling

Tags: java, android, android-alarms

It has come to my attention that Android 5.1 no longer accepts recurring alarms for time intervals shorter than 60 seconds ([source](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=161244)).

I am developing an application that logs information about wireless networks. For the operation of the application it is imperative that it can perform its operations every 1-2 seconds and that it doesn't get killed or suspended by the operating system even if it is using a lot of resources. Reliable operation over long periods of time (several hours) is the most important thing. Impact on battery life is not a concern.

So far the most reliable way of achieving this functionality has been to use recurring alarms. Now with Android 5.1 that is no longer an option. What would be my best options for replacing the AlarmManager implementation?

Comment: IMHO, there are 2 possible solutions - to set 60 alarms or to implement service with foreground mode.

Comment: Foreground service was one of the first things I tried. The logger was killed by the OS all the time. Setting 60 alarms is something that never even occurred to me. That is definitely worth a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Note that your app will not work on Android 6.0 and higher when the device is in Doze mode.

Comment: @CommonsWare I believe that at least in the Android M preview the Doze mode can be disabled on an app-by-app basis. If that is the case with the public release version it would not be a big problem since our application is aimed at highly trained professionals who can easily be instructed to turn off Doze mode for the app.

Comment: "the Doze mode can be disabled on an app-by-app basis" -- no. You are thinking of app standby, which, while related, is not doze mode. Doze mode affects all apps for motionless/non-charging devices. Now, if your devices happen to always be on a charger, then Doze mode will not kick in while the charger is working (e.g., no power outage in the building).

Comment: @ViktorYakunin Your idea of scheduling 60 alarms works really well. You should post it as an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you can set up 60 alarms to get flexible solution for your current implementation. Check OS version and set up as many alarms as you  need.

But for a long-term solution I suggest you to implement sticky foreground service which would work similar to music player. Something simple like Handler.postDelayed should be enough to keep it alive. The reason to do this way is that alarms are not accurate and it is always better to have some control on the process.